# python function to transform list of Python dictionaries

Tags: python

Input:

```
[{'item': 'milk', 'inventory': 1}, {'item': 'eggs', 'inventory': 0}, \
{'item': 'bread', 'inventory': 6}, {'item': 'sugar', 'inventory': 12}]
```

Expected Output:

```
[{'item': 'milk', 'inventory_level': 'Low'}, {'item': 'eggs', 'inventory_level': 'None'}, \
{'item': 'bread', 'inventory_level': 'Normal'}, {'item': 'sugar', 'inventory_level': 'Normal'}]
```

Inventory Condition:

0 or less: None

1 or 2: Low

3 or more: Normal

function to output like above example

Can someone please help to write python function to transform array of json object?

Comment: Please show your code. If you've made a specific error, we can help. I don't think json is involved in this question. Yes, you use the json library to read the original json text to data and to write out the final json from the transformed data, but none of that matters in the function that actually does the transform.

Comment: @KennyOstrom think what they are calling a "json object" is actually a python dictionary

Comment: Your input data does not represent a valid Python construct. Please show the actual data you're working with and the code that's not working for you

Comment: ...and it is not valid JSON either.

Comment: I can give a hint. Write a function that takes int and returns the inventory level string. Use that in a list comprehension. First you'll need to put your data in a valid format and hopefully eliminate some of the redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

This will transform your input list of Python dictionaries. Note: there is no JSON here.

Also note that this is destructive. If you want non-destructive version then take a copy of your input list and work on that.

```
data = [
    {'item': 'milk', 'inventory': 1},
    {'item': 'eggs', 'inventory': 0},
    {'item': 'bread', 'inventory': 6},
    {'item': 'sugar', 'inventory': 12}
    ]

def itext(n):
    return 'None' if n is None or n <= 0 else 'Normal' if n > 2 else 'Low'

for d in data:
    d['inventory_level'] = itext(d.pop('inventory', 0))

print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'item': 'milk', 'inventory_level': 'Low'}, {'item': 'eggs', 'inventory_level': 'None'}, {'item': 'bread', 'inventory_level': 'Normal'}, {'item': 'sugar', 'inventory_level': 'Normal'}]
```